# has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. vue to spring

Tags: vue.js

Use axios from vue to spring
Causes error when connecting
What's the problem?

1. vue component script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW3nN.png)

2.vue.config.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mew68.png)

3.Spring controller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbSPk.png)

4.error code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pmNc.png)

I want console log

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to tell the controller method to enable CORS via CrossOrigin annotation on the method. So in your case just edit the controller method to this:

```
@GetMapping("/getNoticeList")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public String getNoticeList() {
  return "asdsad";
}
```

Assuming that you run your frontend app on port 3000.